# Hibernate ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm trying to map an Oracle database with Java using Hibernate but I'm facing an issue. Here is the code :

Java app :

```
package guival.tp3.bdd;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import org.hibernate.*;

public class Scenariste extends Personne {
    private int idScenariste;

    public int getIdScenariste() {
        return idScenariste;
    }

    public void setIdScenariste(int idScenariste) {
        this.idScenariste = idScenariste;
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session uneSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction uneTransaction = uneSession.beginTransaction();

        Scenariste scenar = new Scenariste();
        scenar.setDateNaissance(LocalDate.now());
        scenar.setNom("fefef");
        scenar.setPrenom("fefzefzfz");

        uneSession.save(scenar);

        uneTransaction.commit();
        uneSession.close();

        HibernateUtil.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Hibernate config file :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/system</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">---</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">---</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

        <!-- SQL to stdout logging -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

        <mapping resource="guival/tp3/bdd/Scenariste.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Hibernate Scenariste table mapping file :

```
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="guival.tp3.bdd.Scenariste" table="SCENARISTE">

    <id name="idScenariste" column="ID_SCENARISTE" type="integer" unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">SEQ_SCENARISTE</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

    <property name="nom">
        <column name="NOM" sql-type="VARCHAR2(50)"/>
    </property>

    <property name="prenom">
        <column name="PRENOM" sql-type="VARCHAR2(50)"/>
    </property>

    <property name="dateNaissance">
        <column name="DATE_NAISSANCE" sql-type="DATE"/>
    </property>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

And the SCENARISTE table looks like that :

[image: DB Scenariste table]

I also made a trigger in the database to increment the ID_SCENARISTE column.

When I run this code I have this error : `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY`

Here are the last lines of the Hibernate log when the error occurs :

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        SEQ_SCENARISTE.nextval 
    from
        dual
Hibernate: 
    /* insert guival.tp3.bdd.Scenariste
        */ insert 
        into
            SCENARISTE
            (NOM, PRENOM, DATE_NAISSANCE, ID_SCENARISTE) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?)
déc. 02, 2018 6:48:55 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 932, SQLState: 42000
déc. 02, 2018 6:48:55 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: ORA-00932: types de données incohérents ; attendu : NUMBER ; obtenu : BINARY
```

I'm using Hibernate 3.2.0.cr5 and Java SE 8.

Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score -2):

Try removing the data type like this

```
 <id name="idScenariste" column="ID_SCENARISTE" unsaved-value="0">
        <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">SEQ_SCENARISTE</param>
        </generator>
 </id>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jose. I tried to remove the datatype like you said but still have the same error.